# Mozilla not using http2

Tags: apache, http2, mozilla, webmin

Mozilla Browser doesn't use http2 on my online site, but it uses http2 on my local.lan site. Weird, since both are coming from the very same server. I tested http2 availability via curl and got a 200 response with all headers. The only difference between my local and my online site, is the online version has more restrictions, and more modules in use. So my question is is there any module that Mozilla prevents using http2? Any help would be greatfull.

Comment: [`(3) Only supports HTTP/2 if the server supports protocol negotiation via ALPN`](https://caniuse.com/?search=http2)

Comment: Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve]: The only information you give us is that one server has "more restrictions and more modules". I assume an answer that states "try less restriction and less modules" wouldn't be helpful, but that's the level of detail that we could give you with the situation you describe. Writing a good question, with appropriate details, sometimes is even enough to answer the question yourself while coming up with the descriptions - we certainly rely on those details.

Comment: Maybe it's because I still have the ssl protocol still enabled, on my local.lan site it's disabled. Thanks, both of you.  I give a feedback as soon as I got home.

Answer (score 0):

Hei,
first of all. I will thank u all. There wasn't any http2 issue. with firefox, i totally forgot about the service worker.
Unregistered the worker and, all seems fine.

i'm the one to blame.